# Retrieving data from firebase depending on (City)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

I am working on iOS application using swift, and I have the following data in firebase dashboard of the application

```
Users =     
{
    "07a5fa11-2a09-455b-92bf-a86dcd9d3e3e" =         
     {
        Name = "Hissah";
        Category = "Art & Designe";
        City = "Riyadh";
        Email = "H@him.fm";
        ShortDescription = "";
    };
    "08e5443c-cdde-4fda-8733-8c4fce75dd34" =         
    {
        Name = "Sara";
        Category = "Cheefs";
        City = "Dubai";
        Email = "Sara@gmail.com";
        ShortDescription = "best cake ever . ";
    };
```

How can I retrieve the (Name) of the users whose (City) is "Riyadh" to a table view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Firebase documentation is a great source of information that provides solutions to many common use-cases. This particular one is covered in the [documentation on querying](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tossing this in the ring as it's a straightforward answer and addresses a dataSource that can be used to populate a tableView

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com/users")

ref.queryOrderedByChild("City").queryEqualToValue("Riyadh")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            //iterate over all the values read in and add each name
            //  to an array
            for child in snapshot.children {
              let name = child.value["Name"] as! NSString
              self.tableViewDataSourceArray.append(name)
            }

            //the tableView uses the tableViewDataSourceArray
            // as it's dataSource
            self.tableView.reloadData() 

})
```

Edit: A follow up comment asked how to add the text to a NSTextView

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("City").queryEqualToValue("Riyadh")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            //iterate over all the values and add them to a string
            var s = String()
            for child in snapshot.children {
              let name = child.value["Name"] as! NSString
              s += name + "\n" // the \n puts each name on a line
            }

            //add the string we just build to a textView
            let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: s)
            self.myTextView.textStorage?.appendAttributedString(attrString)

})
```

Comment: I am really confused.
To make it easier, can you tell me how I can retrieve them into a (text view) instead of (table view), please.

Answer (score 0):

With your current node "Users" you would have to download all users and individually check to see which ones have the city "Riyadh". This would be a waste because you would be reading a lot of data you might not need.

If searching for users by city is a main feature of your app I would make another node "Cities" which would contain a list of cities. Each city node would then contain a list of all the users in that city and you could query that node. Then if you need more information on those users you know which specific people to look up in your "Users" node. You could then use this information however you see fit in your table view.

```
Cities:
{
    "Riyadh": 
        {
          "07a5fa11-2a09-455b-92bf-a86dcd9d3e3e":true
        },
    "Dubai":
        {
          "08e5443c-cdde-4fda-8733-8c4fce75dd34":true
        }
},
Users:     
{
    "07a5fa11-2a09-455b-92bf-a86dcd9d3e3e":         
     {
        Name: "Hissah";
        Category: "Art & Designe";
        City: "Riyadh";
        Email: "H@him.fm";
        ShortDescription: "";
    };
    "08e5443c-cdde-4fda-8733-8c4fce75dd34":         
    {
        Name: "Sara";
        Category: "Cheefs";
        City: "Dubai";
        Email: "Sara@gmail.com";
        ShortDescription: "best cake ever . ";
    };
```

Further reading here, where it talks about denormalizing data:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: Great data structure. But the part about having to download all users is not true. `ref.queryOrderedByChild("City").queryEqualToValue("Riyadh")` would do the trick. So while your data structure is better (because not doing a query is cheaper than doing a query), it is not strictly needed for this case.

Comment: When I use the structure above by adding another node called city, how I can retrieve the (Name) of all users in "Dubai" city for example?

Comment: Well in my example above you can get the uid of every user per city. Then you can use these uid's to get more information about a particular uid from your Users node.

Comment: @Hissah : So, for the dubai example. If you retrieve all the children for node "Cities/Dubai" You will get all the uids under Dubai, which in this case happens to be just 08e5443c-cdde-4fda-8733-8c4fce75dd34. You could then retrieve the node "Users/08e5443c-cdde-4fda-8733-8c4fce75dd34", which would retrieve all of that childs information. In this case that would be the user "Sara".